# ASP.NET Core Web API: How to implement Stored Procedure output in ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures, ado.net

In ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, I have this stored procedure in a Sybase DB. The stored procedure is to be used to append name based on condition.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_employees
    @psAggregatorId varchar(80),
    @psAcctNo       varchar(20),
    @psAppend2Name  varchar(40),   
    @rsErrorText    varchar(255) OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE 
        @nRC                   int
        ,@nPtid                 numeric(12,0)
        ,@sAcctType             char(2)
        ,@nRimNo                int
        ,@nClassCode            int
        ,@nBranchNo             int
        ,@nRsmId                int
        ,@sOdOption             char(1)
        ,@nEmplId               int
        ,@nChannelId            int
        ,@sTitle1               varchar(60)
        ,@sTitle2               varchar(60)
        ,@sAggregatorName       varchar(200)   
    
    /* Default values */
    SELECT @nEmplId    = 0,
           @nChannelId = 295 
    
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM database1..employee_transfer_account 
               WHERE acct_no = @psAcctNo AND renamed = 'Y')
    BEGIN
        SELECT @rsErrorText = @psAcctNo + " has been previously renamed"
        RETURN -2000000
    END
    
    SELECT @sAggregatorName = aggregator_name
    FROM database1..employee_transfer_aggregator
    WHERE aggregator_name = @psAggregatorId
    
    IF @@rowcount = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @rsErrorText = "System could not retrieve Merchant record"
        RETURN -2000011      
    END

    SELECT 
        @sAcctType  = acct_type,
        @nRimNo     = rim_no,
        @nClassCode = class_code,
        @nBranchNo  = branch_no,
        @nRsmId     = rsm_id,
        @sOdOption  = od_option,
        @sTitle1    = title_1,
        @sTitle2    = title_2
    FROM 
        database1..dp_acct
    WHERE
        acct_no = @psAcctNo
    
    IF @@rowcount = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @rsErrorText = "System could not retrieve record"
        RETURN -2000012      
    END
      
    select @sTitle1  = @sAggregatorName + ' - '
    
    select @sTitle2  = @psAppend2Name   
    
    exec @nRC = sp_tpi_acct
        'Update'              -- @psAction
        ,@nRimNo
        ,@psAcctNo
        ,@sAcctType
        ,@nClassCode
        ,@nBranchNo
        ,@nRsmId
        ,@sTitle1       -- @psTitle1
        ,@sTitle2        -- @psTitle2
        ,@sOdOption
        ,@nEmplId
        ,@nChannelId
        ,@rsErrorText   output
        
    if @nRC != 0 or @@error != 0
    begin
        select @rsErrorText = convert(varchar(20),@nRC) + "|" + @rsErrorText
        return -2000013
    end


   -- Flag account flagged as renamed
    update database1..employee_transfer_account
    set renamed = 'Y'
        ,rename_dt = getdate()
        ,virtual_name = @sTitle1 + ' ' + @sTitle2
    where acct_no = @psAcctNo
    
    if @@rowcount = 0
    begin
        select @rsErrorText = "System could not update managed account record"
        return -2000014      
    end        

return 1
```

If successful, it is to display

```
@psAcctNo appended successfully with @psAppend2Name
```

But if it fails or renamed = 'Y', then it should display the content of `@rsErrorText`.

I have written the code in my ASP.NET Core Web API.

Response:

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public Response(bool success, T data)
    {
        Success = success;
        Data = data;
    }

    public Response()
    {
    }
}
```

DTO:

```
public class AppendRequestDto
{
    [Required]
    public string AcctNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AppendName { get; set; }
}
```

Service:

```
public Response<object> AppendAccount(AppendRequestDto model)
{
    var response = new Response<object>();

    try
    {
        using (AseConnection con = new AseConnection(aseConnection))
        {
            AseCommand cmd = new AseCommand("sp_employees", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var aggregatorId = CodeUsername.Username; 

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@psAggregatorId", aggregatorId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@psAcctNo", model.AcctNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@psAppend2Name", model.AppendName);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }

        response.Data = $"{model.AcctNumber} appended successfully with {model.AppendName}";
        response.Success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error($"An error occurred " + ex.ToString());
        response.Success = false;
    }

    return response;
}
```

As stated earlier, I have written the code that takes care of when it is successful. If successful, it displays in the response

```
response.Data = $"{model.AcctNumber} appended successfully with {model.AppendName}";
response.Success = true;
```

But how do I adjust the code for when it fails or renamed = 'Y', and then make it display the content of `@rsErrorText` from the stored procedure in the .NET Core as part of the response?

Take note that `@rsErrorText` is required.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on your structure, maybe you need to add a field to `AppendRequestDto` to accept `@rsErrorText`. In addition, do you have a certain condition to judge whether it is successful or not? If this condition can be obtained, whether it can be judged directly in `AppendAccount`?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using THROW or RAISEERROR statements in your stored procedure when you need to report an error back to the user, and handle the error coming back to your command object. You can read the error text from the SQLException, and process it accordingly.